# Replace content inbetween <form> tags with sed

Tags: bash, perl, sed, scripting

I have a folder containing html files with forms on them, I need to find and replace the form tags, with a different set of form tags. I am currently using sed with no avail using this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
REPLACEWITH="<form method='post' action=''><?php include('form.php'); ?><\/form>"
sed -r "s/(<form>)(.*)(<\/form>)/\1$REPLACEWITH\3/" -i index.html
```

Am I doing this right? I can't seem to get it to work!  Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not good idea to parse html with a regex see here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your `sed` command needs to have some of the escapes removed.  Neither `f` nor `>` need to be escaped:

   ```
    sed -E "s/(<form>)(.*)(<\/form>)/\1$REPLACEWITH\3/"
   ```

   Under the POSIX spec, the meaning of `\>` is undefined.  If you are using GNU `sed`, the it is interpreted as the end of a word.  But in your case, you need a literal `>`.

   In `sed`, `\f` means a form feed while you needed a literal `f`.
2. Also, an escape is needed for the slash near the end of `REPLACEWITH`:

   ```
   REPLACEWITH="<form method='post' action=''><?php include("form.php"); ?><\/form>"
   ```

   Unescaped, this would confuse the substitute command.

The need to escape slashes could be removed if a different delimiter was used the for substitute command.  For example, use `s|old|new|` in place of `s/old/new/`.

As the commenter pointed out, regex is a limited tool for editing html in all of its potential complexity.  If your html file, though, is known to have relatively simple and predictable form, then regex may very well be the simplest solution.

#### The complete script

```
REPLACEWITH="<form method='post' action=''><?php include("form.php"); ?><\/form>"
sed -i -r "s/(<form>)(.*)(<\/form>)/\1$REPLACEWITH\3/"  target_file.html
```

Comment: @user3547033 It runs for me.  I just tested it again and it still runs for me.  What error do you see?  Is the script that you are using exactly the same as what I show above as the "complete script"?

Comment: @user3547033 I copied the code from your updated question to my computer and it ran fine for me.  Does it give you any error messages?  What OS are you using?  (Unix utilities on OSX often have subtle incompatibilities.)